# jQuery data attribute not working

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have the following code:

**Html**

```
<div id="Test" class="test">test</div>
<div id="Test1" class="test">test</div>
<div data-id="Test2" class="test">test</div>
<br />
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var result1 = 'Result1:',
    result2 = 'Result2:';

$('.test').each(function () {
    var test = $(this),
        testId1 = (typeof this.id !== "undefined" ? this.id : test.data('id')),
        testId2 = (typeof this.id !== "undefined" ? this.id : '');

    if (testId2 == '') {
        testId2 = test.data('id');
    }

    result1 += testId1 + '.';
    result2 += testId2 + '.';
});

$('#result1').html(result1);
$('#result2').html(result2);
```

For both result divs I would expect their content to be `Result1:Test.Test1.Test2.` and `Result2:Test.Test1.Test2.`

Yet the first result div has contents of `Result1:Test.Test1..`.

Why is this?

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaJ5n/1/)

Comment: Well logging `typeof(this.id)` yields String 3 times...even tho ID clearly isn't there in the third div. Weird

Comment: @Sarcastic `.data(id)`  is correct check --> http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is for the 3rd element even though `id` attribute is not there `this.id` is not `undefined` it is an empty string. So for the 3rd element `test1` gets an empty string as the value but for `test2` the following `if` condition updates the value with the `id` data value.

One possible solution is to test the length of the `id` property instead of checking whether it is defined or not

```
var result1 = 'Result1:',
    result2 = 'Result2:';
$('.test').each(function () {
    var test = $(this),
        testId1 = ($.trim(this.id || '').length ? this.id : test.data('id')),
        testId2 = (this.id !== undefined ? this.id : '');

    if (testId2 == '') {
        testId2 = test.data('id');
    }

    result1 += testId1 + '.';
    result2 += testId2 + '.';
});

$('#result1').html(result1);
$('#result2').html(result2);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3wKdJ/)

Comment: thanks I was scratching my head for ages on this wondering why it wasn't working - seems daft that it is always defined even though it doesn't exist - or is that part of the default constructor for a js element?

Answer (score 2):

If an element has no id, element.id returns an empty string, not undefined.

Could fix and simplify :

```
 var testId1 = this.id ? this.id : test.data('id');
```

Comment: very nice, I like the neat way of doing this

Comment: Thanks. Actually @Joe's answer is even shorter : `var testId1 = this.id || test.data('id');` Plus this pattern allows more than 2 possible values very easily, just keep going : `var testId1 = this.id || test.data('id') || test.data('default') || 'blop';`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `typeof this.id` is a `string` even when it has no value set.

Because of this, the condition `typeof this.id !== "undefined"` is always true and hence both fields always have only `this.id` as value.

You should just try it the below way:

```
var test = $(this),
    testId1 = (this.id !== "" ? this.id : test.data('id')),
    testId2 = (this.id !== "" ? this.id : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var result1 = 'Result1:',
    result2 = 'Result2:';
$('.test').each(function () {
    var test = $(this),
        testId1 = (test.attr('id')!=undefined ? test.attr('id') : test.data('id')),
        testId2 = (test.attr('id')!=undefined ? test.attr('id') : '');
    if (testId2 == '') {
        testId2 = test.data('id');
    }
    result1 += testId1 + '.';
    result2 += testId2 + '.';
});

$('#result1').html(result1);
$('#result2').html(result2);
```

**Fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/WaJ5n/3/

Answer (score -2):

Your misstake is the html code, the id="Test2" needs to have the id tag not data-id="Test2"

```
<div id="Test" class="test">test</div>
<div id="Test1" class="test">test</div>
<div **id="Test2"** class="test">test</div>
<br />
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

This will give you the outpoot your are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Modify this line.

```
<div data-id="Test2" class="test">test</div> to

<div id="Test2" class="test">test</div>
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/VxLUk/)**

Comment: He wants it to see that there is no ID and get data("id") instead, not rewrite the html.